# Combination of echo, pipe and cat

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe

I have a file name called `temp.csv` in my script one of the intermediate step is

```
echo "some info" > final.csv | cat temp.csv >> final.csv
```

at times the file `final.csv` is created without data which is in `temp.csv` (when it is running through scheduler). And then, when I rerun the job, then the `final.csv` is created as I expected.

Why it is happening like this (what exactly happening in the command `echo "some info" > final.csv | cat temp.csv >> final.csv`)?
If I replace the command in the following way:

```
echo "some info" > final.csv ; cat temp.csv >> final.csv
```

will this modification be helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are piping the output from `echo "some info" > final.csv` into `cat temp.csv >> final.csv`, so these two commands (`echo` and `cat`) run in parallel.

Because of that, what ends up in the `final.csv` depends on what program gets scheduled. What you want to do is replace that `|` with a `;`. And then the `echo` command will run until finished, and only then `cat` is started.

Comment: Why would the commands run in parallel if the latter one needs the former one to finish in order to receive the former's output piped to its input?

Comment: @confused00 Why would they not, the latter one only needs the former to finish, to be able to finish itself. It can process what it gets in parallel.

Comment: @confused00 - read up on how pipes work. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79501/executing-piped-commands-in-parallel

Answer (score 4):

`|` mean `pipe` == output of the previous command *piped to* next command input. If you use `> final.csv` that redirect output of `echo` into file and remains nothing to pipe.
So to correct you free use 2 command separatelly as you have offered above or use pipe if your want

```
echo "some info" | cat - temp.csv > final.csv
```

Other do the same

```
cat - temp.csv <<<"some info" > final.csv
```